# IOS load view controller again from the view placed inside it

Tags: ios, ipad, navigation

im working on an `iPad` application which is almost near to finish, but here I'm stuck on a situation.

the app has a main page where the user can read article and navigate to other articles by categories or by clicking a featured article, subcategories and featured articles are tables inside the same view controller

every thing works well but here is the problem.

the table featured articles is inside a view and that view handles its delegate and datasources. (have separate .h and .m files) this view Controller imports view's .h file to display table view.

now i want the featured article to open in this page when user taps on it. for this i simply can use (thnkAuthorsPage is the above view controller and this code is inside the view)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        thnkAuthorsPage  *AuthorsPage = [[thnkAuthorsPage alloc] initWithNibNameAndAuthor:@"thnkAuthorsPage" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] authorObject:[carouselList objectAtIndex:index]];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:AuthorsPage animated:YES];
    }
```

but the problem is that when i import the `thnkAuthorsPage`.h file in view it give errors.

what i am guessing is that probably its a kind of loop thnkAuthorsPage view controller imports view .h file and view has to import thnkAuthorsPage.h file

i guess you have understood the problem so suggest me how can i accomplish this functionally

thanks

Comment: no. cant understand your question

Comment: sorry i cant post a snapshot, but i need to use the parent view controller inside a view which is already imported in parent view.

Comment: try the answer by wain. It will work. In view.h instead of #import use @class

Comment: OK it worked i placed a @class thnkAuthorsPage in .h file and then import the thnkAuthorsPage.h in .m file and it worked 
thank you guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .h file for both classes, don't use `#import`, use `@class` instead. Then import in the .m file. This limits the import knowledge and avoids circularities.

Comment: ok i placed @class thnkArticlesDisplay in subview's .h file and then in .m file i tried to initialise the view controller
 thnkArticlesDisplay  *ArticlePage = [[thnkArticlesDisplay alloc] initwithnibname ....;
but it gives error